# while altering for primary key i am getting this error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ddl

```
ALTER TABLE VASTHRA_TALLY_BRIDGE.DBO.[VF_TALLY_MIGRATION_VOUCHER_DETAILS_GST_19_20] 
WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT
VASTHRA_TALLY_BRIDGE.DBO.[VF_TALLY_MIGRATION_VOUCHER_DETAILS_GST_19_20] 
PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED  
( 
    voucher_Number,
    voucher_date,
    Debit Account Head,
    Credit Account Head,
    ITEM_NAME,
    RATE
)  ON [PRIMARY] END
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: I removed the `postgresql` tag as this is clearly a SQL Server error message

Comment: After the word `CONSTRAINT` you're meant to give the name you want for the constraint. Not repeat the table name (complete with DB and schema names)

Answer (score 6):

Constraint name does not need nor DB neither schema specification here.

Columns with spaces must be enquoted.

```
ALTER TABLE VASTHRA_TALLY_BRIDGE.DBO.[VF_TALLY_MIGRATION_VOUCHER_DETAILS_GST_19_20] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT
 [VF_TALLY_MIGRATION_VOUCHER_DETAILS_GST_19_20] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED  
 ( voucher_Number,voucher_date,
   [Debit Account Head],[Credit Account Head],ITEM_NAME,RATE)  
ON [PRIMARY]
```

`END` keyword is illegal here since no `BEGIN` specified.

Answer (score 2):

You are naming your constraint `VASTHRA_TALLY_BRIDGE.DBO.[VF_TALLY_MIGRATION_VOUCHER_DETAILS_GST_19_20]`. An object, so a constraint as well, is not allowed to have dots in its name. So, you should give it a different name, for example `PK_VF_TALLY_MIGRATION_VOUCHER_DETAILS_GST_19_20`.